Add kubernetes pod labels to splunk logs using k8sattributes processor
How to add pod labels to splunk logs? Can't get the syntax right and the documentation doesn't seem to cover it. I'm using the otel-collector in daemonset mode, running in a kubernetes cluster and using the splunk_hec exporter.
Using the k8sattributes processor:
data:
  relay: |
    exporters:
      splunk_hec:
...
    processors:
      k8sattributes:
        auth_type: serviceAccount
        passthrough: true
        extract:
          # Extract these labels from the source pod to use later
          labels:
            - from: pod
              key: app.kubernetes.io/component
              tag_name: app.label.component
            - from: pod
              key: app.kubernetes.io/instance
              tag_name: app.label.instance
            - from: pod
              key: app.kubernetes.io/managed-by
              tag_name: app.label.managed_by
            - from: pod
              key: app.kubernetes.io/name
              tag_name: app.label.name
            - from: pod
              key: app.kubernetes.io/part-of
              tag_name: app.label.part_of
            - from: pod
              key: app.kubernetes.io/version
              tag_name: app.label.version
            - from: pod
              key: helm.sh/chart
              tag_name: helm_chart
            - from: pod
              key: pod-template-hash
              tag_name: label.pod_template_hash
          metadata:
            - k8s.namespace.name
            - k8s.node.name
            - k8s.pod.name
            - k8s.pod.uid
            - container.id
            - container.image.name
            - container.image.tag
        filter:
          node_from_env_var: K8S_NODE_NAME
        pod_association:
        - sources:
          - from: resource_attribute
            name: k8s.pod.uid
        - sources:
          - from: resource_attribute
            name: k8s.pod.ip
        - sources:
          - from: resource_attribute
            name: ip
        - sources:
          - from: connection
        - sources:
          - from: resource_attribute
            name: host.name
...
    receivers:
      filelog:
        include_file_path: true
        include:
        - /var/log/pods/*/*/*.log
        operators:
        - id: container_parser
          type: container
          add_metadata_from_filepath: true
        - type: json_parser
          if: '$body matches "^{"'
        ### Use the k8sattributes processor from earlier to add labels to the splunk event
        # This does not work
        - type: add
          field: resource["app.kubernetes.io/component"]
          value: EXPR(attributes["k8s.pod.labels.app.kubernetes.io/component"])
        - type: move
          from: attributes["log.file.path"]
          to: resource["filename"]
        - type: add
          field: resource["cluster_name"]
          value: x
        - type: move
          from: attributes.log
          to: body
          if: attributes.log != nil
        poll_interval: 200ms
        retry_on_failure:
          enabled: true
        start_at: beginning
    service:
      extensions:
      - health_check
      pipelines:
        logs:
          receivers:
          - filelog
          processors:
          - k8sattributes
          exporters:
          - splunk_hec

I would like the labels to be added to the splunk event, as tags/labels/attributes, it just doesn't seem like the syntax matches up?

From the [tag:kubernetes] tag wiki: KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here.
